# Font size in Jtextpane looks smaller then in other applications

Tags: java, fonts, size, jtextpane, jtextcomponent

I have JTextPane and if i write something into it with e.g. font size 12 then it looks smaller than text in e.g. MS Word with same size and same font family.

I've searched on the internet and I found that this is not just my specific problem. But I can't find any solution.

Set the bigger font size is not a solution for me.

[image]

Is it possible to change measure or something like that?

Comment: just use +1p or +2p more in your app

Comment: I said that is not a solution for me. I need work with this size later. For example I need to save it to the RTF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is DPI difference of java (72pixels per inch) and windows (96 pixels per inch). To reflect your fonts properly you can multiply them on the 96/72 on Windows.

You can override

```
public Font getFont(AttributeSet attr)
```

method of DefaultStyledDocument where retrieve font size from the attribute set and increase it with the proportion.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a trick for that. Through the Document of the JTextPane, you're able to specify the font-size of each character with setCharacterAttributes. Now imagine that you have some text with font-size 12 and then a text with font-size 14 inside your JTextPane. What happens if you edit the global font-size of the JTextPane using

```
myTextPane.setFont(myTextPane.getFont().deriveFont(newFontSize));
```

The answer is that your text will still be considered sized 12 and 14, but will be displayed bigger !

WARNING : I didn't try with a StyledDocument. Only with an HTMLDocument.